# Access linux server file system directly from Windows for development

Tags: linux, windows, development

I am developing for an Arch **linux server** and I am looking for software to reduce the time it takes to copy the project to the server every time I changed something from my windows machine.

I tried *FileZilla* and copied my project on the server, but that is annoying and takes time.

I also tried a program that mounted the directory so I had access to it from a windows folder via *sftp* which is extremely slow but suits my needs.

Is there any other way to save my file on the windows machine and have the saved file on the linux machine within at most a second?

Clouds take so much time to sync or I didn't set them up properly. Any recommendations?

Comment: I'm on mobile and messed up the formatting, sorry for that

Comment: It sounds like you want things to transfer faster than your network and filesystems allow. So no...

Comment: I have very small files that I change and when I copy each file that I edited via FileZilla, it is damn fast. But it is too much effort to exactly copy only the files that I edited. It is possible and I could write an application that uses sftp properly and syncs it exactly how I want I guess, but that takes even more time

Comment: You want to look into rsync.

Comment: Thank you, I will. I let you know if it helps me once I'm home

Comment: SFTP is quite fast, I maintain a rather remote server with it (but I use a Linux client). How fast and reliable is the network between you and the server? If Filezilla is fast enough, there are editors that can use FTP rather transparently IIRC (UltraEdit...)

Comment: Network is pretty reliable and fast. FTP isn't safe though, right?

Answer (score 1):

Use *[Samba](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/samba)* on the Linux server.

Samba uses the SMB protocol, just the same that Windows uses to share directories in a network.

So, the server can publish a shared directory that you will mount on your windows machine as a shared drive just like this [tutorial](https://confluence.crbs.ucsd.edu/display/CRBS/Mount+a+Samba+share+on+Windows) shows.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest rsync, because it can only move changed / new files. But you're doing development. Oh please, just use a git repository on both dev host and server, then pull the changes.

Comment: I'm fine with pushing the changes, but can I push them directly into the folder I need them? I don't want to pull manually on the server and I need these files within 1-2 seconds available on the server

Comment: It's git, it's distributed, just have the repo in the folder where you need the files. Instead of pulling from the server, you can just push from the dev host. If it works with github, why shouldn't it work with your setup?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'm using [Mountain Duck](https://mountainduck.io/) (Shareware) for this purpose. It allows me to mount a sftp share on Windows, but since you have already tested that and the speed does not seem sufficient for you the only other option I see is to install the samba server and share you development folder using a CIFS share which you can directly access from Windows (\\server\folder).

For Arch linux the steps seem to be:

- Install the package with pacman: `sudo pacman -S samba`
- Copy the example configuration file: `sudo cp /etc/samba/smb.conf.default /etc/samba/smb.conf`
- Set up the samba share: edit `/etc/samba/smb.conf` and add:

  ```
  [MyFolder]
  path = /path/to/folder
  inherit permissions = yes
  inherit owner = yes
  ```
- Check the configuration file for syntax errors: `testparm`
- set the samba password: `sudo smbpasswd some_user` (that user should have access to the folder of course)
- Restart the service to apply new changes: `sudo systemctl restart smbd nmbd`

Comment: I said I use arch

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I only noticed the bold font :-) I'll update my response

Comment: No worries. I wasn't even able to format at all on mobile, every help is appreciated

Comment: That looks pretty straight forward. I'll give it a try

Comment: Just can't get it to work. I always get an error that the port 445 is not responding when I try to access the shared folder

Comment: Hmm... Is there any firewall in between your server and the windows machine? Some Netfilter/IPTables running on the server (you can check with `sudo iptables -vnxL`)? Can you post the output of `ps -Af | grep -i smb` and `sudo netstat -anlp | grep 445`?

Comment: Could take a day until I'm able to. But I remember that the second output showed an ip address like 0.0.0.0 and some addition